# SQLAlchemy: Pass information to automap many to many relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

We're converting a codebase to SqlAlchemy, where there's an existing database that we can modify but not completely replace.

There's a collection of widgets, and for each widget we keep track of the 20 most similar other widgets (this is a directional relationship, i.e. `widget_2` can appear in `widget_1`'s most similar widgets, but not vice versa).

- There's a `widget` table which has a `widget_id` field and some other things.
- There's a `similarity` table which has `first_widget_id`, `second_widget_id` and `similarity_score`. We only save the 20 most similar widgets in the database, so that every `widget_id` appears exactly 20 times as `first_widget_id`.
- `first_widget_id` and `second_widget_id` have foreign keys pointing to the `widget` table.

We're using SQLAlchemy's automap functionality, so a `Widget` object has a `Widget.similarity_collection` field. However, for a specified `widget_id`, it only includes items where `second_widget_id == widget_id`, whereas we want `first_widget_id == widget_id`. I understand that SQLAlchemy has no way to know which of the 2 it should pick.

Can we tell it somehow?

EDIT: as per the comment, here are more details on the models:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `similarity` (
  `first_widget_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `second_widget_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `score` int(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`first_widget_id`,`second_widget_id`),
  KEY `first_widget_id` (`first_widget_id`),
  KEY `second_widget_id_index` (`second_widget_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `similarity`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `similar_first_widget_id_to_widgets_foreign_key` FOREIGN KEY (`first_widget_id`) REFERENCES `widgets` (`widget_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `similar_second_widget_id_to_widgets_foreign_key` FOREIGN KEY (`second_widget_id`) REFERENCES `widgets` (`widget_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `widgets` (
  `widget_id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `widget_name` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`game_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=13179 ;
```

And using this python code to initialize SQLAlchemy:

```
base = automap_base()

engine = create_engine(
    'mysql://%s:%s@%s/%s?charset=utf8mb4' % (
        config.DB_USER, config.DB_PASSWD, config.DB_HOST, config.DB_NAME
    ), echo=False
)

# reflect the tables
base.prepare(self.engine, reflect=True)

Widgets = base.classes.widgets
```

Now when we do something like:

```
session.query(Widgets).filter_by(widget_id=1).similarity_collection
```

We get `sqlalchemy.ext.automap.similar` objects for which `second_widget_id == 1`, whereas we want `first_widget_id == 1`

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about your models? Though you automap, perhaps create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that mirrors the issue you're having. It sounds like you might be looking for [foreign_keys](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html) param of a relationship in order to handle multiple join paths, but I cannot be sure.

Comment: Updated with all the relevant code. Hopefully it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override how the `similarity_collection` joins, even when automapping, with an [explicit class definition](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html#specifying-classes-explicitly) and passing [`foreign_keys`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.foreign_keys) to the relationship:

```
base = automap_base()

engine = create_engine(
    'mysql://%s:%s@%s/%s?charset=utf8mb4' % (
        config.DB_USER, config.DB_PASSWD, config.DB_HOST, config.DB_NAME
    ), echo=False
)

# The class definition that ensures certain join path for the relationship.
# Rest of the mapping is automapped upon reflecting.
class Widgets(base):
    __tablename__ = 'widgets'

    similarity_collection = relationship(
        'similarity', foreign_keys='similarity.first_widget_id')

base.prepare(self.engine, reflect=True)
```

If you wish to also control the created relationship(s) in `similarity` – for neat association proxies or such – use the same pattern.

Comment: Great! I didn't realise it's possible to manually help automap like that. Thanks a lot!